# ionic 4 "ion-option" text wrap

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am working with ionic 4 and i am having a problem trying to do a text wrap inside a "ion-select"

my select looks like this:

[image]

if i change my css directly on google chrome ( Style section on the "inspect element" menu) to "white-space: pre-wrap"

It looks like this:

[image]

and this is what i want to get.

on my HTML code i have this:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Dirección de Entrega<a style="color: brown;">*</a></ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="ordHerder.addressId" popover >
    <ion-option style="white-space: pre-wrap !important;" *ngFor="let item of register_data.directions" value="{{item.recId}}" text-wrap>{{item.direction}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

and my css:

```
shopping-car-delivery {
    .alert-ios .alert-radio-label{ white-space: pre-wrap !important;}
    .alert-md .alert-radio-label{ white-space: pre-wrap !important;}
    .alert-wp .alert-radio-label{ white-space: pre-wrap !important;}
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm struggling as well with this.

Answer (score 5):

just add this in your app.scss if you are using ionic 4

```
.alert-radio-label.sc-ion-alert-md {
  white-space: pre-line !important;
}

.alert-radio-label.sc-ion-alert-ios {
  white-space: pre-line !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to app.scss worked:

```
ion-label {
   white-space: normal !important;
}
```

Comment: ionic 4 doesn't have app.scss are you sure this solution is not for Ionic 2/3?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by overriding `alert-radio-label.sc-ion-alert-md` , `alert-radio-label.sc-ion-alert-ios` and updating whitespace to pre-line in page.scss

```
.alert-radio-label.sc-ion-alert-md {
  padding-left: 52px;
  padding-right: 26px;
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  flex: 1;
  color: var(--ion-color-step-850, #262626);
  font-size: 14px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Also, reduced font-size to 14px, since my text was around 35-40 characters.

[image].

Comment: it worked for me in ionic4, can you please specify reason why this will not work?

Comment: I can modify this in Chrome debugger and see the results but where do you make this change in the actual code?  It does nothing when I add it to .css

Comment: @D.Hodges overide alert-radio-label.sc-ion-alert-md , alert-radio-label.sc-ion-alert-ios in your .scss

Answer (score 1):

If none of the above solutions works try root level css changes like below

```
   :root {
  ion-popover ion-select-popover ion-radio-group ion-item ion-label{
            white-space: pre-line !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: After hours of searching, this was the only solution that worked for me using ionic 5 and 6.

Answer (score 0):

the css [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)  should be extended to *pre-line* so your `.scss` would be

```
 shopping-car-delivery {
    .alert-ios .alert-radio-label{ white-space: pre-line !important;}
    .alert-md .alert-radio-label{ white-space: pre-line !important;}
    .alert-wp .alert-radio-label{ white-space: pre-line !important;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are with Ionic 4 then just use `class="ion-text-wrap"` for wrapping text anywhere in element.

Ionic 4 CSS Classes Reference :- https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities

For Ionic 3 you can use `class="text-wrap"`

Answer (score 0):

> By default, select uses the AlertController API to open up the overlay
>   of options in an alert. The interface can be changed to use the
>   **ActionSheetController API** or **PopoverController** **API** by passing
>   action-sheet or popover, respectively, to the interface property.

To customize the ion-select options  with `interface="popover"` in ionic, do the following:

**Solution**: Add the code in **global.scss(Ionic4)** and **outside page-app tags in app.scss(Ionic3)** so that the following css is accessible outside the component

```
.popover-content ion-list ion-label
    {
    font-size:12px !important;
    }
```

**Detailed Explanation:**

- The problem is that options inside ion-select are added as a Popover/Alert/Actionsheet.
- **The HTML code for showing the ion-select interface is produced outside the component i.e. outside the ion-router-outlet component.**
- So, any code you put inside your component's scss file to change looks of ion-select options will not reflect in the browser.

**Example:** How DOM looks like: (Ionic 4)
[image: How select options are added in Ionic 4 DOM]

Ionic 3[image: How select options are added in Ionic 3 DOM]

**`This will change the look of ion-select option throughout the App`**

To customize it for different pages, I did it by adding and removing a custom class from the main app selector

```
ionViewDidEnter()
{
let appRoot:any=document.getElementById('myAPP');
this.renderer.setElementClass(appRoot,'customIonSelectCSS',true); //add
}

ionViewDidEnter()
{
let appRoot:any=document.getElementById('myAPP');
this.renderer.setElementClass(appRoot,'customIonSelectCSS',false); //remove
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ion-select is using the alert to show the options, so you need to override the default styles

Step1:

```
.alert-tappable.sc-ion-alert-md.sc-ion-alert-ios {
    display: contents !important;
}
```

by default, display: flex; change it to the display: contents !important;

Step2:

```
.alert-radio-label { white-space:   pre-wrap !important; }
```

by default, white-space: nowrap; change it to white-space: pre-line !important;